# mysql copy database rows from database 1 multiple times to new database 2, looping through a value of database 3

Tags: mysql, copy, rows, multiple-tables

I want to copy values from on table to another using mysql, while looping through a third table to set a specific value in the second.

Table 1 is called countries, with structure and data:

```
countries
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ countries_id + countries_name + countries_iso_code_2 + countries_iso_code_3 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1            + Belgium        + BE                   + BEL                  +
+ 2            + Netherlands    + NL                   + NLD                  +
+ 3            + Germany        + DE                   + DEU                  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The rows countries_id and countries_name need to be copied to table countries_name. For each language_id from table languages.
Table 2

```
countries_name
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ countries_id + language_id + countries_name +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1            + 1           + Belgium        +
+ 2            + 1           + Netherlands    +
+ 3            + 1           + Germany        +
+ 1            + 3           + Belgium        +
+ 2            + 3           + Netherlands    +
+ 3            + 3           + Germany        +
+ 1            + 4           + Belgium        +
+ 2            + 4           + Netherlands    +
+ 3            + 4           + Germany        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

table 3

```
languages
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ languages_id + name    + code +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1            + English + en   +
+ 3            + Dutch   + nl   +
+ 4            + German  + de   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I know how to do this for a single pass, but not for multiple.

`CREATE TABLE countries_name (`

`countries_id int(11) NOT NULL,`

`language_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,`

`countries_name varchar(64) NOT NULL,`

`UNIQUE countries (countries_id, language_id),`

`KEY idx_countries_name_zen (countries_name)`

`) ENGINE=MyISAM;`

`INSERT INTO countries_name (countries_id, countries_name)`

`SELECT c.countries_id, c.countries_name`

`FROM countries c;`

Comment: so, provide your code how you do that for a single pass?

Comment: code for single pass added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd3c7/1

If I got your goal correctly:

```
INSERT INTO countries_name (countries_id, language_id, countries_name)
SELECT 
c.countries_id, 
l.languages_id,
c.countries_name
FROM countries c
LEFT JOIN languages l
ON 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is is only for the first language, now the query needs to loop through the remaining languages, and copy the the names again with the other language id's

Comment: Of course I did :)  The query only copies the set once, only for language_id 1, and not for 3 and 4

Comment: Very strange. I'll need to investigate this further.
Edit:
I must have f***ked up the query somewhere, as I tried again a few minutes ago and now it is working perfect.
Thank you very much.